# Prove that the following polynomials are irreducible or not.

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

> I want to show that:
>
> **1)** $X^4+1$ is irreducible

The roots are the elements of 
$$\left\{\frac{\pm 1+i}{\sqrt 2},\frac{\pm 1-i}{\sqrt 2}\right\}$$

therefore it's not a product of a polynomial of degree 1 and a polynomial of degree 3. Is there an easier way to prove that it's not of the form $(X^2+aX+1)(X^2+bX+1)$ than to solve the system $(X^2+aX+1)(X^2+bX+1)=X^4+1$ ?

> **2)** $X^4-16X^2+4$ is irreducible

It's easy to prove that there is no integer roots, therefore it's not a product of a polynomial of degree 1 and a polynomial of degree 3. I suppose that 
$$X^4-16X+4=(X^2+aX+b)(X^2+cX+d)$$
$$\iff X^4-16X^2+4= X^4+(a+c)X^3+(b+d+ac)X^2+(bc+da)X+bd$$

$$\iff\begin{cases}a+c=0,\quad(1)\\
b+d+ac=-16, \quad (2)\\
bc+da=0,\quad (3)\\
bd=4,\quad (4)\end{cases}$$

By $(4)$ we have that $(b,d)\in\{(1,4),(-1,-4), (2,2), (-2,-2)\}$. By $(1)$, $a=-c$. By $(3)$, $bc+da=bc-dc=c(b-d)=0$, therefore $c=0$ or $b=d$. If $c=0$, then by $(2)$, $b+d=-16$ and no elements of $\{(1,4),(-1,-4), (2,2), (-2,-2)\}$ satisfy this equation, then $c\neq 0$. Therefore $b=d$, and by $(4)$, $b^2$=4 therefore $b=d=\pm 2$. But by $(2)$, $$2b-c^2=-16\implies c^2=16+4=20\implies c=\pm\sqrt{20}\notin \mathbb Z,$$ therefore, the polynomial is irreducible on $\mathbb Q$.

*It looks ok ? is there an easier proof ?*

> **3)** $X^4+X^2+\frac{1}{2}$

I have no idea. Actually, the real question is **compute the degree of the extension $\mathbb Q(i,\alpha)/\mathbb Q$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $X^4+X^2+\frac{1}{2}$.**
 There is maybe an other way to solve the problem. If it can help, the root of this polynomial are the elements of
$$\left\{\frac{i}{\sqrt 2}\sqrt{1-i},-\frac{i}{\sqrt 2}\sqrt{1-i},\frac{i}{\sqrt 2}\sqrt{1+i},-\frac{i}{\sqrt 2}\sqrt{1+i}\right\}$$

Comment: Polynomials are not irreducible in abstract. Your first polynomial can be factorised into linear factors over $\mathbb C$ and into quadratic factors over $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$

Comment: @MarkBennet I think irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ was heavily implied

Comment: @Mathmo123 Indeed. However, it is helpful to get into good habits and specify.

Comment: what is not clear ?

Answer (score 1):

$1)$ : $$f(x)=x^4+1$$
       $$f(x+1)=x^4+4x^3+6x^2+4x+2$$

and the criterion of Eisenstein shows that $f(x+1)$ is irreducible. Therefore
 $f(x)$ is also irreducible.

Comment: very nice ! Thanks,

Comment: 3) : $f(x)=2x^4+2x^2+1$ is irreducible modulo $3$, so $f(x)$ is irreducible over $Q$

Comment: I have no good idea about 2) yet.

Comment: You could use kroneckers method : Take $f(-1)=-11$ $f(0)=4$ $f(1)=-11$ and find all triples $(a,b,c)$, such that $a$ divides $f(-1)=-11$, $b$ divides $f(0)=4$ and $c$ divides $f(1)=-11$.

Comment: For each those triple find the interpolatinf polynomial $g(x)$, such thaat $g(-1)=a$ $g(0)=b$ and $g(1)=c$. Check all those polynomials, if they divide $f$. If there is none, $f$ has no factor with degree $2$.

Comment: This method is rather cumbersome and not efficient, but it works.